# Windows 10 Icon

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

"If you don’t see the Get Windows 10 app on your PC, it might be because:

Your device isn’t up-to-date with at least Windows 7 SP1 or Windows 8.1 Update.

Windows Update is turned off or is not set to received updates automatically.

You’ve blocked or uninstalled the necessary Windows Update functionality.

Your device is not running genuine Windows."

My computer meets all of these criteria, I still do not have the Windoes 10 Icon displayed.

Comment: This is a great summary of the current answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You missed one point.

- Your computer might not be compatible with Windows 10.

If you are sure that it is compatible, you might try the steps in this [article](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-get-the-windows-10-upgrade-icon-if-its-missing/)